# Step progression in simple proof of Jensen's inequality assuming differentiability

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

> Suppose that $\phi$ is a function, convex and differentiable. We wish
>   to prove that $E(\phi(x)) \geq \phi (E(X))$. Let $\mu$ denote the
>   mean, $E(X)$. We have that
>   $$ 
> \phi(x) \geq \phi(\mu) + \phi'(\mu)
> (x-\mu) 
> $$ because $\phi$ is always greater than its tangent line at $\mu$,
>   since it is convex. Then it follows that
>
> \begin{align} 
> E(\phi(x)) &\geq E(\phi(\mu) + \phi'(\mu) (X- \mu)) \\ 
> &= \phi(\mu) + \phi'(\mu)E(X-\mu)\\ 
> &= \phi(E(X)). 
> \end{align}
>
> Thus concludes the proof.

I understand that the inequalities progress so thanks to the linearity of expectation, so that a manipulation such as $E(aX+bY) = aE(X) + bE(Y)$ is allowed. However, does $E(a+bX) = a+ bE(X)$ necessarily hold true? Also, am I correct in understanding that $E(X-\mu) = 0$, which allows us to transition from the second step to the third?

Comment: It would be preferable to write your final two inequalities as equalities.

Comment: @aduh Thank you, fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see that $E(a + bX) = a + bE(X)$ holds, let $X=1$ (a.s. if you like) and apply linearity as you've written it. To see that $E(X - \mu) = 0$ apply linearity again: $E(X - \mu) = E(X) - E(\mu) = \mu- \mu=0$.